# Why is $q$ sometimes a complex number, but other times a prime power?

Tags: representation-theory, quantum-groups, q-analogs, quantum-calculus

In the fields of representation theory and [quantum algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/q/290522/64073), we often start with some $\mathbf{C}$-algebra and study it's quantization as an algebra over $\mathbf{C}(q)$, using the algebra structure to *twist* the multiplication. But what is $q$? Taking the calculus-flavored approach like in [Quantum Calculus](https://www.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-0071-7) by Kac and Cheung, $q$ is just some indeterminate complex number: we specialize $q \to 1$ to get our original un-quantized object back, or we need $|q|<1$ for certain series to converge, or we specialize $q$ to some root of unity to make $q$ have finite order.

But in other applications, like counting subspaces of a vector space over $F_q$, or defining the structure constants of the [Hall algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_algebra) of a $F_q$-linear category, we use the same $q$-calculus framework, but we are now thinking of $q$ as a power of a prime.

How do we consolidate the calculus interpretation of $q$ as an element of our base field with the combinatorial interpretation of $q$ as a prime power?

Comment: We consolidate it by making $q$ an indeterminate, which is what they've already done.

Comment: @MattSamuel But, like, there's got to be some meaningful connection between the two interpretations of $q$, right? It must be more than a happy accident that we get neat combinatorial facts from considering $q$ as a prime power.

Comment: This is an excellent question. Also look up the so-called "cyclic-sieving phenomena," whose explanation at least in some cases is isotypical decompositions (a la representation theory), IIRC.